# Constant weight codes with distance $4$ and weight $2$, $A(n,4,2)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Maybe a strange question but on https://oeis.org/A001839 for $A(n,4,3)$ the first comment says that "Maximal number of edge-disjoint $K_3$'s in a $K_n$." and in my understanding, this extends to any other weight $w$, i.e., "Maximal number of edge-disjoint $K_w$'s in a $K_n$." is simply $A(n,4,w)$. Is this correct?

In this sense, we can also consider $A(n,4,2)$ which gives $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, since two $K_2$ are edge disjoint iff they are not the same. But his grows very rapidely in $n$ compared to the values of $A(n,4,3)$ for example. Am I making a mistake somewhere? Or what do I missunderstand about constant weight codes interpreted in this graph theoretic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the definition, $A(n,d,w)$ is the maximum size of a binary code with word length $n$, minimum distance $d$, and constant weight $w$.

For $(,4,3)$, how do we see it as maximal number of edge-disjoint $_3$'s in a $_$?

Consider a code-word with weight $3$. The triangles are formed by connecting the index of the non-zero entries together. For example, 111000 corresponds to the triangle formed by connecting the vertices $1,2$, and $3$, whereas 110001 corresponds to the triangle formed by connecting the vertices $1,2$, and $6$.

If the weight has to be $3$ and distance $4$, the code-words must have at most one vertex in common (i.e. any two triangles can have at most one common vertex, hence edge-disjoint).

For $A(n,4,2)$, we can of course think of them as edges, but with distance at least $4$, we cannot have any overlap between codewords at all. This gives us $n/2$ instead.

You can take a look at https://oeis.org/A001843 for $A(n,4,4)$ and see if it corresponds to your new understanding.

Comment: So, a for $w=2$ they can't share any vertices, for $w=3$, no edges, then for $w=4$ no shared triangles? This would mean than $A(n,d,w)$ is the maximal number of $w$ simplex in a $n$ simplex such that no two share a $w-1$ simplex?

Comment: @Jfischer You're forgetting the dependence on $d$! If you want to treat the sets as $w$-simplices in an $n$-simplex, then at most they can share a $(w - \frac d2)$-simplex. (But if you meant $d=4$, you are correct.)

Comment: Sorry, for me $d$ always equals $4$. But this would imply that they do not share $w-2$ simplicies in my case, deduced from your formula.

Answer (score 2):

The generalization to packing edge-disjoint $K_w$'s in $K_n$ is given by $A(n,2w-2,w)$: that's $A(n,2,2)$, $A(n,4,3)$, $A(n,6,4)$, $A(n,8,5)$, and so on. The idea is that two $K_w$'s are edge-disjoint precisely when they share at most one vertex. When two $K_w$'s share only one vertex, there are $w-1$ vertices in each $K_w$ that are not in the other, for a total distance of $2(w-1)$ between their vertex sets.

On the OEIS, the sequence with $a(n)=\binom n2$ is too famous to be described as $A(n,2,2)$, which is after all a silly case from the point of view of coding theory. (In general, $A(n,2,w) = \binom nw$, since any two codewords of the same weight that are not equal are at distance at least $2$, and there are $\binom nw$ total code words of weight $2$.)

The next case of edge-disjoint $K_w$'s after $w=3$ is $A(n,6,4)$, which is [A004037](https://oeis.org/A004037) on the OEIS. The connection to packing edge-disjoint $K_4$'s is not mentioned in the OEIS comments, but the entry does cite an article of A.E. Brouwer on [Optimal packings of $K_4$'s into a $K_n$](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(79)90105-5).